# Get Android activities and sub activities path programmatically

Tags: applications, adb, automation, system-apps

This is my first question on AE forum, so excuse me for my ignorance.

I'm searching for a method to get the complete path through the system apps like Music, Video, Settings, etc...

The goal is to prepare a checklist for manual testers to browse through the checklist and do sanity/functional tests

Currently, I'm using :

```
adb logcat | find "ActivityManager"
```

Then I record the path manually to prepare the script for launching the activity, for example:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$WifiSettingsActivity
```

The problem I can't go through all the forms of the system apps this way because it's time-consuming

Is there any tool, idea to help me automate the process of launching system apps activities one by one to create a full checklist ?

Regards

Comment: Not programmatically: There are apps for this. This one is just for browsing, but sure you will find one with record mode https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut

Comment: @alecxs Thank you for the suggestion, but is there something else which makes me gain in productivity? an automated way to get all launchable activities with their intents ?

Comment: I've edited the question, Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441138/how-to-find-out-activity-names-in-a-package-android-adb-shell

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441138/how-to-find-out-activity-names-in-a-package-android-adb-shell) from StackOverflow, you can try the following:

```
adb shell dumpsys package | grep -i "com." | grep Activity
```

It will list all activities from packages whose names start with `com.`. You can apply the same command for packages that start with `net.` or `org.` or whatever by substituting `com.`